# Use of Document doc = new Document(); in lucene?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

Below is my code.

```
Document doc = new Document();
String str = "Lucene in Action"; //first document
doc.add(new Field("title", newString,Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
writer.addDocument(doc);
System.out.println(doc.getFields());
```

If I need to index 1000 documents so do I need to run the above code for that 1000 documents, if yes then how can we run this code in a loop, I tried making array of type Document but it isn't allowing me to do that. How can I get out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create document and add field to it once and then just change value of that field before writing document to index

```
Document doc = new Document();
StringField stringField = new StringField(<your_name>, "", Field.Store.YES);
doc.add(stringField);

....

for (String value : <ListOfStrings>) {
    stringField.setStringValue(value);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not ready-to-use-example, but I guess the idea itself could be helpful.

You could extract document creation into the method:

```
// methods params should be everything you need every time you want to create a new document
// input param str is instead of this String str = "Lucene in Action";
// it's not used but I left it in case you need it
public Document createDocument(String str, 
                               String newString, 
                               Field.Store storeVal,
                               Field.Index indexVal) {
    final Document doc = new Document();
    // if you need to add many fields - you can do it here also
    // let's say having this in the loop as well
    doc.add(new Field("title", newString, storeVal, indexVal));
    return document;
}
```

Now if you need it multiple times, you could try something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    final Document doc = createDocument(<!-- pass some args here -->);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    System.out.println(doc.getFields()); // just am example. does not mean you need it :) 
}
```

Hope it's somehow useful.

Happy Hacking :)